# play online video on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i want to play video without storing on my iphone device. so how can i establish the connection.please help me ..what are the step to be done for playing the video..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is video uploaded in a server ? or you have the url of the video?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464732/how-do-i-stream-video-and-play-it

Answer (score 0):

- First, [check if you need to implement HTTP Live Streaming](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-DontLinkElementID_20)
- Playing the video is dead simple, check [the iPhone programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW36)