# iPhone reading a broadcast transmission

Tags: iphone, ios4, broadcast

I have a server that should send a broadcast transimission, which I have to read in an iPhone App. I searched in the net, but I didn't find anything. I'm able to play a video starting from its URL, so my question is: how can I play in my iPhone a broadcast transmission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTTP Live Streaming protocol in iPhone SDk 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719958/how-to-use-http-live-streaming-protocol-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464732/how-do-i-stream-video-and-play-it , although some of the answers there are out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going answer myself to this old question: the MediaPlayer core simply provides all the stuff to play live transmissions. Simply give him the link of the server and it's done.
Hope it helps.